# Dispatching Redux actions in order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, action, redux-thunk

I currently have an array of indexes and I would like to perform a dispatch action on each element. Other answers I've looked at seem to suggest using `Promise.all`. However, order matters and if I use `Promise.all` the promises are executed out of order. I tried an async and await and it works well, but I don't know if it's the best practice. Is this alright to do in an action?

```
const someAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
  for (const element of allElements) {
    await dispatch(doThisAction(element));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's legal, *but*, we recommend that you should:

- [Avoid dispatching many actions sequentially](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#avoid-dispatching-many-actions-sequentially)
- [Model actions as "events" instead of "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters)
- [Allow many reducers to respond to the same action](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action)

So, in this case, I would dispatch a single action containing all of the data from the response.

The exact mechanics involved depend on what you're trying to specifically accomplish here.